# can't call function in "+(void)" function in xcode

Tags: objective-c, function

When I try to call a function in a `+(void)`function it is not working.

example:

```
+(void) publicfunction {
[self otherFunction];
}

-(void) otherFunction{
self.scene.view.pause = YES
}
```

but I can't call "`otherFunction`" inside of `+(void)publicFunction`.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
+(void) publicfunction {
    [YourClassName otherfunction];
}
```

"+" is static method it neither require an instance nor can they implicitly access the data (or this, self, Me, etc.) of such an instance

And you need to change your other function class to "+" as well.

But if you need an access to your "self" properties. you should not use static methods - instead keep reference to your object and make those as normal methods.

Comment: This is also no working =/   Classname otherfunction

Comment: you need to replace "YourClassName" with your class name - i don't know what is it

Comment: yes i know, I did but it is not working at all. Do I have to write something in the .h file or so?

Comment: You need to make other function + as well.

Comment: What about the parameter in that function + ?

Comment: @dedicatedCoder it works as any other functions so you can pass parameters there

Comment: ok. @GrzegorzKrukowski.

Answer (score 2):

You can't call an instance method like `- (void)otherFunction` unless you have an **instance** of the class.

Often, methods (not "functions") such as `publicFunction` return instances of their type.  In those cases, they create an object and prepare it as necessary.  Consider the `[NSString stringWith...]` style of method.